# Pass to dwr function string stored in html input

Tags: javascript, html, dwr

I'm trying to pass to my dwr function the content of an html input of my page. The content of this input is changed programmatically by the user.

If i pass to my DWR method an hard coded string, the method succedes. The problem is when i give the method the content of the input. DWR just retrieves error.

The DWR function is:

```
function myDWRFunction(str) {

readyProxyJS.javaImplementatedFunction(str, function (data) {

    $('#profileImage').attr('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.concat(data));

});}
```

And this is the content of my jsp page (in other words, from where i'm calling the dwr method):

```
<input type="text" name="dynamicContent"/>

<input id="bula" type="button" value="READY" onclick="myDWRFunction(document.getElementsByName('dynamicContent'[0].value;)"/>
```

i'm not going to post the rest of the DWR implementation since, as i've written before, if i pass an hard-coded string to the method **(example: onclick="myDWRFunction('thisIsMyHardCodedString'))** , all works fine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Missing closing `)` at `document.getElementsByName()` call `myDWRFunction(document.getElementsByName('dynamicContent')[0].value)`

Comment: Thanks, but still not the problem... i forgot the bracket posting this question...